# ActiveSync, sunchronize "storage card" folder with PC

Tags: windows-xp, sync, windows-mobile

I have a Pidion 5000 mobile device. Is it possible to synchronize storage card (ProgramStore folder) with a desktop folder?

Desktop: Windows XP (Home Edition)
Pidion: Windows Mobile 6 (Classic)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about that device, but if you can put the storage card directly in your pc or map it as a drive in any way - or even through the device, it is visible as a folder, you could use standard sync tools such as [Microsoft Sync Toy](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) which I know works very well.

Comment: I can open the mobile folder with windows explorer but not with Sync Toy. Sync Toy seems great, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect your device using mass storage connection, which can be found in settings/connections/usb to pc .... then sync toy can map any of your folder location on storage card and sync files....tested on HTC touch2 phones.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how that mobile device works, but if it is just a regular memory card like SD or CompactFlash, you could maybe try to use [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) and auto-run or something? Create a command that does the sync you need, put it in a [batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bat) and put it on the card. Then create an auto-run file that starts the batch file whenever the memory card is connected to the computer.

If the Pidion can run robocopy and access a shared network folder on your desktop, you could also maybe just create a batch file that does the sync directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect your mobile device your storage card is assigned a Drive letter

You can then set up either Sync Toy as Wil suggested, but I think [SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/) is a little better (as in more advanced settings without getting in the way).

Follow [this guide](http://www.2brightsparks.com/tutorials/syncyourlaptop/3.html) to set it up if you want it to sync both ways

Comment: Unfortunately, that storage card doesn't get a drive letter.

Comment: Are you able to find it with Explorer?

Comment: I can open it with windows file explorer.

Comment: I can access the device (it's on the drives tree) as "Mobile Device".

Comment: It must have an address, SyncBack can also locate network drives, perhaps it can be recognized as such?

Comment: If it doesn't work, I guess it's too much trouble to put your card in a card reader? I can't find any (good) freeware programs that do syncing with a WinMo device part from ActiveSync